# rest-client gem: 401 unauthorized with token

Tags: rest-client

I am using the [rest-client gem](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) to try and make a post to my API.

> The RestClient.post helper requires three arguments to pass headers like that: .post(url, params, headers). Have you tried something more like this?
>
> RestClient.post('http://api.example.com/', {key: 'value'}, authorization: 'a2m...')

https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/issues/339#issuecomment-71787018

I have followed the advice above but receive `RestClient::Unauthorized - 401 Unauthorized` as the response.

My code:

```
RestClient.post "http://api.example-dev.com:7000/v1/resources", {key: 'value'}, :authorization => 'yyyyyyyy'
```

I have success with the below curl command but not the above RestClient.post. Successful curl:

```
curl -i -X POST -d 'test[key]=1234' -H "Authorization: Token token=yyyyyyyyyyyyyy" \ http://api.example-dev.com:7000/v1/resources
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should produce the same request as curl:

```
`RestClient.post "http://api.example-dev.com:7000/v1/resources", {:test => {key: '1234'}}, :authorization => 'Token token=yyyyyyyyyyyyyy'`
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought that rest-client would have automatically added "Token token=" when using `:authorization`. I was incorrect and your answer fixed the problem for me.